# Obtaining symbolic values using Z3

Tags: z3

Please consider the follow statements.

> y := 10
>
> z := x + y

After these two statements are executed "z" has the value "x + 10" where "x" represents a symbolic value; such symbolic values are important in program verification -- for example, to compute the path characteristics using Dijkstra'a weakest pre-condition method.

Now, consider the following code for Z3.

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(declare-const z Int)

(assert (= y 10))
(assert (= z (+ x y)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (z))
```

It produces the following output since it consider the interpretation where "y" has the 10 and "x" has the value 0.

```
sat

((z 10))
```

Is there some way I can make Z3 produce the output "x + 10"? i.e., I am interested in getting the symbolic values in terms of variables that have not been instantiated with any specific values.

Comment: "in terms of variables that have not been instantiated with any specific values": Do you mean unconstrained variables or variables which are constant? If you just want to handle constant, that can be done by simple substitution.

Comment: Since computing weakest pre-condition involves basically substitution -- I think substitution ought to do the job. But like Juan Ospina said, is there no alternative in Z3-SMT-LIB corresponding to his code in Z3Py?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I do think, however, that C++ API has more flexible options than Z3-SMT-LIB.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I think that it is not possible using Z3-SMT-LIB.  But it is possible using Z3Py.

```
x = Int('x')
y = 10
z = x + y
print z
```

and the output is

```
x + 10
```

Comment: This is simply doing substitution. There is no call to the actual solver. If I give to z3py, the following code: {x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
z = Int('z')
prove(And(z == x + y, y == 10))}, I get the output {counterexample
[y = 10, z = 1, x = -10]}, which is not what LKB is looking for. The prove call actually calls the SMT solver.

Comment: Hi Tushar, you are right.  The point is that when the solver is called the output is a numerical value, it is not a symbolic expression.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I know there is a eval function in C++ API in which an z3 expression can be evaluated to another z3 expression by looking into z3 model. If the z3 model is incomplete (ie. it doesn't have valuations for unconstrained variables), then it should be able to give me a Z3 expression which is a symbolic expression rather than a numerical value. However, last I checked, it reports an error and it expects client to set model completion to true, in which case z3 eval will give a numerical value.

Comment: In other words, there is probably something clever(maybe hackish) one can do with a partial model that the Z3 solver gets to get a symbolic expression. Last I checked Z3 C++ API doesn't support that.